# EDIT SOAP of a WCF Service using IClientMessageInspector

Tags: wcf, soap

In my WCF Service, I want to edit the SOAP in BeforeSendRequest and AfterReceiveReply of IClientMessageInspector.

I have created a custom Behavior like this:

```
public class MyBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
{
}
```

in the class MyBehavior, I implemented IEndpointBehavior method Like below code:

```
public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
{
    MyInspector inspector = new MyInspector();
    clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
}
```

MyInspector is nothing but the class which is inherited from IClientMessageInspector.

Now, my question is: ApplyClientBehavior of IEndpointBehavior is not getting fired. But at wcf client, when I add a reference of the project where the MyBehavior class is present and write below code at client side:

```
c.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
```

It works fine. I mean the Apply Client Behavior method getting fired.

I dont want to ask my clients to add this Behavior manually and I want this to happen automatically. How can I achive this?

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.IO;

namespace MethodChangeService
{
   public class MyInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
            reply.WriteMessage(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            doc.Load(ms);
            ChangeMessage(doc, false);
            ms.SetLength(0);
            writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
            doc.WriteTo(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
            reply = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, reply.Version);

        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {
            string action = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>("Action", request.Headers[0].Namespace);
            if (action.Contains("GetData"))
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
                request.WriteMessage(writer);
                writer.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;
                doc.Load(ms);
                ChangeMessage(doc, true);
                ms.SetLength(0);
                writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
                doc.WriteTo(writer);
                writer.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
                request = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
            }
            request.Headers.Action += "1";
            return null;
        }

        void ChangeMessage(XmlDocument doc, bool flag)
        {
            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsManager.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            nsManager.AddNamespace("tempuri", "http://tempuri.org/");
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//s:Body", nsManager);
            if (node != null)
            {
                if (flag)
                    node.InnerXml = node.InnerXml.Replace("GetData", "GetData1");
                else
                    node.InnerXml = node.InnerXml.Replace("GetData1Response", "GetDataResponse").Replace("GetData1Result", "GetDataResult");
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            //endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            MyInspector inspector = new MyInspector();
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new MyBehavior();
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get
            {
                Type t = Type.GetType("MethodChangeService.MyBehavior");
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Service class is:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace MethodChangeService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class HardcoadedService : IHardcoadedService
    {
        public string GetData(int i)
        {
            return string.Format("you entered {0}",i);
        }

        public string GetData1()
        {
            return string.Format("You got redirected to another method!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the client code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HardcoadedServiceClient c = new HardcoadedServiceClient();
            c.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
            string s = c.GetData(3);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you not perform the same on your service with the methods BeforeSendReply and AfterRecieveRequest of IDispatchMessageInspector (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx). Doing so you can use it on your service level and the client will not need to use the IClientMessageInspector. More information on message inspector here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx

Comment: Here is another sample of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352015/how-can-i-create-custom-xml-namespace-attributes-when-consuming-a-legacy-soap-se

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this using the `<behaviors>` and `<extensions>` sections in the `app.config` file for your client.

To register your custom behavior add the following to the `<system.serviceModel>` section of your `app.config` file:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
      <myBehavior/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="myBehavior" type="MethodChangeService.MyBehavior, MethodChangeService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Then in `<endpoint>` element if the `<client>` section add the following attribute:

```
behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior"
```

For more info on this, check out: [Configuring and Extending the Runtime with Behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/configuring-and-extending-the-runtime-with-behaviors)