# .NET SOAP Client Using :Array

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

I'm attempting to add this SOAP endpoint located here: `http://ds.hitpromo.net/product`

However I get the following error:

> Scaffolding Code ... Error:Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail:
>   An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: The datatype 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array'
>   is missing. XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:ProductControllerwsdl']/wsdl:portType[@name='ProductControllerPortType']
>   Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: There was an error importing
>   a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on. XPath to
>   wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:ProductControllerwsdl']/wsdl:portType[@name='ProductControllerPortType']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:ProductControllerwsdl']/wsdl:binding[@name='ProductControllerBinding']
>   Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
>
> Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port
>   is dependent on. XPath to wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:ProductControllerwsdl']/wsdl:binding[@name='ProductControllerBinding']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:ProductControllerwsdl']/wsdl:service[@name='ProductControllerService']/wsdl:port[@name='ProductControllerPort']
>   Error: No endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps were found. An
>   error occurred in the tool.
>
> Failed to generate service reference.

As I understand it, it's because .NET's SOAP generation code doesn't understand to include the types from `xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"` I've read about manually including it but the directions are unclear (including other StackOverflow answers on this subject), downloading the WSDL and using import/include hasn't worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the given address `http://ds.hitpromo.net/product` and successfully added it as a service reference to a project without any problems.

Maybe adding it as a Web Reference might help you out. Can you try "Add Service Reference" =>  Select "Advanced" => Then Select "Add Web Reference" and add it from there.

In the past adding the endpoint as a web reference solved some similar issues for me.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't work for .NET Core AFAIK, I'll have to find a workaround for that.

Comment: @StrangeWill did you find a solution for .NET core?

Answer (score 2):

A couple things you could try:

1.) Create a local copy of the wsdl and remove the offending xml namespace. Then when adding the service reference point it to your local copy.

2.) Try pulling in the service as a Web Reference instead of as a Service Reference. Add Service Reference => Advanced => Add Web Reference.

3.) You might have to go back to .Net 4.x as .Net Core support for SOAP services may not be mature enough to handle legacy WSDLs.

I had a situation that was somewhat similar using .Net 4.5 and WCF - here is a link: [How can I create custom XML namespace attributes when consuming a legacy SOAP service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352015/how-can-i-create-custom-xml-namespace-attributes-when-consuming-a-legacy-soap-se)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this downloading the WSDL file to a specific path. After that I downloaded the https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ XML file like [this](https://gist.github.com/rasputino/b9b513bc17f7989c8d01ebc2157b98a7).

Then I executed svcutil referencing both files and everything worked:

```
svcutil mywsdl.xml schemas.xmlsoap.org_soap_encoding_.xml
```

*Note: dotnet-svcutil didn't work, I used the original svcutil.exe executable. But the result worked with .NET core.*